# LIN communication using LabVIEW

Tags: labview

I am new to do LIN communication using LabVIEW XNET Drivers. I need to read the data frames from one motor using LIN. I transmit the commands to read the data but I did not get any response. I have transmitted the frames, 3C is the Master frame. If I transmit this frame I do not get any data.

[image]

Comment: Do you use XNET database to configure communication? Are IDs of motor correct? Is hardware connection correct? There are multiple factors which could go wrong, so now your question is too broad to answer.